# Изменить путь для java web app на tomcat

Tags: java, servlet, tomcat

Создал проект, когда нажимаю запустить в самом Netbeans запускается норм, т.к. он использует свои настройки. Убедившись, что всё рабоатет, хочу задеплоить НОРМАЛЬНЫМ способом. Пишу в консоли mvn package, беру war файл, кидаю в папку webapps томката. Но чтобы запустить приложение, надо прописать путь, как у папки приложения. Например, http://localhost:8080/folder-spring-1.0/ , а мне нужно тот путь, который прописан в файле META-INF/context.xml . Это возможно?

**UPDATE**

Да. Я сделал это. Правда способ мне не нравится. Я не деплоил файл war куда-либо, просто запаковал проект в war. Далее создал в папке `/conf/Catalina/localhost` файл battleship2.xml C содержимым:

```
<Context reloadable="true"  antiJARLocking="true"
         path="/battleship" docBase="F:\java\Battleship-Web\target\Battleship-Web-1.0.war"/>
```

я прошу обратить внимание на разницу в путях, атрибут path="/battleship" , однако файл называется battleship2.
После этого запустил сервер и приложение стало доступно по адресу `localhost:8080/battleship2`

Теперь ещё вопросы -

1. почему атрибут path проигнорировался? Или я чтото не так сделал?
2. есть ли способ деплоить командой mvn tomcat7:deploy без этих ручных копирований/редактирований файлов?

Comment: А какой там путь? Надо чтоб было `http://host:port/folder-spring` ?

Comment: @0x5a4d обновил первое сообщение

Comment: Как я понял Вы деплоите `Battleship-Web-1.0.war`, и Вам потом не нравится что приложение открывается по адресу `localhost:8080/Battleship-Web-1.0`? Каким сборщиком собираете `.war`?

Comment: Maven'ом собираю. Да, немного не нравится.

Answer (score 1):

Если используете maven, то можно сделать так:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Ваш Групп ID</groupId>
    <artifactId>Артефакт</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}##${project.version}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            ....
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Тогда при сборке maven будет собирать файлы вида `battleship##1.2.3.war`.
При развертывании файла с таким именем (через manager, и просто копированием в webapps) Tomcat установит контекст battleship, а все что после `##` будет воспринято как версия.

[image: Версия web-приложения]

Однако в `webapps` каталог приложения будет по прежнему `battleship##1.2.3`, будьте внимательны.

Документация [Tomcat 7](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html) поможет по context.xml

Пример развертывания приложения на Tomcat 7 при помощи [tomcat7-maven-plugin](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-deploy-maven-based-war-file-to-tomcat/)

Comment: Хех, задал как вы сказали. В итоге в папке проекта в папке target архив появляется с корректным именем, НО в папке сервера (webapps), как появлялся Battleship-Web так и появляется.  Естественно URL проходится вводиться /Battleship-Web/  <finalName>archi</finalName> вот моя строка в pom.xml.

Answer (score 1):

2) Можешь просто reloadable добавить:

```
<Context reloadable="true"  antiJARLocking="true"
     path="/battleship" docBase="F:\java\Battleship-Web\target\Battleship-Web-1.0.war" reloadable="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Некропост, но всё-же...

Открыть настройки tomcat: `sudo nano /opt/dir_tomcat/conf/server.xml` и добавить путь до папки сайта: `<Host name="user.loc" appBase="/home/dir_site/user.loc"/>`

Перезагрузить томкат: `sudo systemctl restart tomcat`

Для локальной разработки, открыть файл: `sudo nano /etc/hosts` и добавить свой хост: `127.0.1.1 user.loc`

Не забудь создать папку `ROOT` в директории сайта и туда уже деплоить свои JSP